# In iOS development, why do they call it a "ViewController" and not just "Controller"?

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller

Why do they call Controllers in iOS `ViewControllers` and not just `Controller`? How is a `Controller` different than a `ViewController`?

ViewController isn't a subclass of Controller. I guess there is no such thing as a plain Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Controller" is a generic term, part of the "Model - View - Controller" architectural triad.

A view controller is a particular type of controller, one that controls a view (and in particular, usually a view that comes and goes nimbly and that, when present, occupies all or most of the screen).

It happens that view controllers thus become the natural locus of most of your app-specific functionality (as opposed to the model, which is just a general data store, and the views, which are obviously general screen-representation widgets). They are thus far and away the most important type of controller in iOS programming. Still, Cocoa does have other controllers that are part of the "Model - View - Controller" architecture but that do *not* control views directly and do not inherit from UIViewController (such as UISearchController).

Comment: It's interesting that ViewController isn't a subclass of Controller. I guess there is no such thing as a plain Controller?

Comment: "Controller" is a generic term, part of the "Model - View - Controller" architectural triad. Gosh, I think I already said that. :) As a class inheritance matter, there would be nothing at all that _all_ controllers would have in common; the notion of a class for controllers-in-general thus makes no sense.

Comment: Alright, I think we are on the same page now. So really they could have just named it UIController but to be more declarative they named it UIViewController so it is clear to the developer that the controller specifically deals with Views. But there is no such thing as a generic Controller as each controller will be a bit specific to its use.

The reason I bring this up is in CakePHP they actually just have a class called Controller:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller

Comment: See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase(v=vs.118).aspx